# The HttpInterceptor in my Angular7 app is not firing during errors, what is wrong in my code?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am planning on using a couple of different interceptors for several things; auth, error handling, etc. I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious, so I'd love to get some extra eyes on it to help me find my mistake.

I'm using Angular7 and I know that I need to use the new HttpClientModule.

app.module.ts:

```
  import { HttpClientModule }      from '@angular/common/http';

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],

  providers: [
      AuthService,
      ErrorInterceptor],
```

errorInterceptor.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor() { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {

            const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
            return throwError('yo you got an error =>', error);
        }));
    }
}
```

my.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getSomeData() {
        this.http.post<any>(`https://getsomedata.com/youneedthisdata`, {})
            .pipe(map(response => {
                console.log('test service', response);
            })).subscribe();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any other code. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where is your ErrorInterceptor provided?

Comment: @MikeTung just made an edit and added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you need special syntax to provide the interceptor.

```
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true }
```

needs to go under your providers array in place of what you currently have for ErrorInterceptor.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Tung! This did it for me. If I have multiple interceptors will I need to use this syntax for each one? Or is there a way to do include multiple in this line? Maybe something like , useClass: [ErrorInterceptor, AuthInterceptor]?

Comment: Must be one at a time because the provide interface is meant for one symbol